# Restsharp Windows Phone 8 Support and FileNotLoad Exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I have upgraded my WP7 app to WP8 and I seem to have a problem in which I can't find a proper solution.

I've tried downloading WatTmdb source code, update the restsharp .dll, build the project and try to use the new assemblies and nothing, also my project is using RestSharp 103.4.0.0 and not 104.1.0.0

The thing is that I'm using the RestSharp API with another API in this app and it works fine.

Any suggestions?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp.WindowsPhone, Version=104.1.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)



System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146234304
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp.WindowsPhone, Version=104.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=WatTmdb.WindowsPhone
  StackTrace:
       at WatTmdb.V3.Tmdb..ctor(String apiKey, String language)
       at WatTmdb.V3.Tmdb..ctor(String apiKey)
       at Series.Views.Search..ctor()
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

I was using two different API's that were relying on RestSharp and on import one had the version 103.4.0.0 and the other was on 104.1.0.0
so I downloaded the latter referenced it and it worked like a charm.